# What does df.repartition with no column arguments partition on?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In PySpark the repartition module has an optional columns argument which will of course repartition your dataframe by that key.

My question is - how does Spark repartition when there's no key? I couldn't dig any further into the source code to find where this goes through Spark itself.

```
def repartition(self, numPartitions, *cols):
    """
    Returns a new :class:`DataFrame` partitioned by the given partitioning expressions. The
    resulting DataFrame is hash partitioned.

    :param numPartitions:
        can be an int to specify the target number of partitions or a Column.
        If it is a Column, it will be used as the first partitioning column. If not specified,
        the default number of partitions is used.

    .. versionchanged:: 1.6
       Added optional arguments to specify the partitioning columns. Also made numPartitions
       optional if partitioning columns are specified.

    >>> df.repartition(10).rdd.getNumPartitions()
    10
    >>> data = df.union(df).repartition("age")
    >>> data.show()
    +---+-----+
    |age| name|
    +---+-----+
    |  5|  Bob|
    |  5|  Bob|
    |  2|Alice|
    |  2|Alice|
    +---+-----+
    >>> data = data.repartition(7, "age")
    >>> data.show()
    +---+-----+
    |age| name|
    +---+-----+
    |  2|Alice|
    |  5|  Bob|
    |  2|Alice|
    |  5|  Bob|
    +---+-----+
    >>> data.rdd.getNumPartitions()
    7
    """
    if isinstance(numPartitions, int):
        if len(cols) == 0:
            return DataFrame(self._jdf.repartition(numPartitions), self.sql_ctx)
        else:
            return DataFrame(
                self._jdf.repartition(numPartitions, self._jcols(*cols)), self.sql_ctx)
    elif isinstance(numPartitions, (basestring, Column)):
        cols = (numPartitions, ) + cols
        return DataFrame(self._jdf.repartition(self._jcols(*cols)), self.sql_ctx)
    else:
        raise TypeError("numPartitions should be an int or Column")
```

For example: it's totally fine to call these lines but I have no idea what it's actually doing. Is it a hash of the entire line? Perhaps the first column in the dataframe?

```
df_2 = df_1\
       .where(sf.col('some_column') == 1)\
       .repartition(32)\
       .alias('df_2')
```

Comment: Did my answer helped you to understand how repartition works without key?

Answer (score 9):

By default, If there is no partitioner specified the partitioning is not based upon characteristic of data but it is distributed in random and uniform way across nodes.

The repartition algorithm behind `df.repartition` does a full data shuffle and equally distributes the data among the partitions. To reduce shuffling it is better to use `df.coalesce`

Here is some good explanation how to repartition with `DataFrame`
https://medium.com/@mrpowers/managing-spark-partitions-with-coalesce-and-repartition-4050c57ad5c4

Comment: So it just uses the row number? It would be great if I could get a reference to it in the source code.

Comment: What I understand, it does not use any information from your dataset, no hask key, it just repartion data in a way that they are uniformely distributed (every partition having same size)

It make sense, even other frameworks like apache kafka does not need key to partition data. Apache Kafka partition data using Round Robin by default if no key provided

Comment: @Stefan Repcek , is there any way I can partition the data based on the total size of dataframe ? i.e. assume i need each partition 128m , if i have 1GB , i have to repartition 1024 , if i have 5GB , i have to repartition 5120 ....so repartition number should be calculated dynamically.

Comment: The link doesn't work. I think this is the right one now: https://medium.com/@mrpowers/managing-spark-partitions-with-coalesce-and-repartition-4050c57ad5c4