# Spark repartition is not working as expected

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, datastax, parquet

I am using spark-sql 2.3.1,   I set

```
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=40
```

in  my code  '

```
val partitioned_df =  vals_df.repartition(col("model_id"),col("fiscal_year"),col("fiscal_quarter"))
```

When i say

```
println(" Number of partitions : " + partitioned_df.rdd.getNumPartitions)
```

It is giving 40 as output , infact after repartition ideally the count should be around 400 , Why repartition is not working here ? What am I making wrong here? how to fix it ?

Comment: Why do you expect 400 partitions instead of 40 that you requested? What do you mean ideally repartitioned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does df.repartition with no column arguments partition on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53529974/what-does-df-repartition-with-no-column-arguments-partition-on)

Comment: I am interested in if you have reached a point of view on this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=40
```

This applies to JOINs and AGGregations only was my understanding.

Try something like this - my own example:

```
val df2 = df.repartition(40, $"c1", $"c2")
```

Here is the output of

```
val df2 = df.repartition(40, $"c1", $"c2").explain 

== Physical Plan ==
Exchange hashpartitioning(c1#114, c2#115, 40)
...
```

Can set num partitions dynamically:

```
n = some calculation
val df2 = df.repartition(n, $"c1", $"c2").explain
```

Comment: one basic dobut , here df is partitioned by 40 , so what role $"c1" and $"c2" plays ???  ... in my machine "$" is not been recognized , but "col" is being recognized , so what to do if "$" need to recognized ?

Comment: I am not sure of your point, I just followed your lead from your thread. So, I note -3 now, what are you concerned about in facf? May be we are not getting the point.

Comment: I am trying to save df2 data to Cassandra 3 node cluster i.e. val df2 = df.repartition(40) , Cassandra concurrent threads failing to write so much data , hence I want to repartition to smaller chunks , ...I cant have a fixed number of partition like 40 , to morrow my df2 records might be less , so i am trying to dynamically paritition based on the columns $"c1", $"c2" , how to do it ?

Comment: Works for me, so I am a little surprised. c1 and c2 are arbitrary column names I used, see if val df3 = df.repartition(40, col("c1"), col("c2")) also works provided you have imported import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ or implicits.

Comment: But that ids an entirely different question. Is that what you want to know?

Comment: thank you .  I think this works only python ...i.e. df.repartition(40, col("c1"), col("c2")) , scala not sure

Comment: Tried it with Scala. val = should indicate that.

Comment: spark.default.parallelism Vs spark.sql.shuffle.partitions , if I set spark.default.parallelism = 20 , spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=5 , what is the number of partitions I get? how to use these ?

Comment: You can try it, but I am actually going into a plane now. The repartition and value you set are key. Most things apply when you do not explicitly set. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

This is to be expected, [the scaladoc for `repartition`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@repartition(partitionExprs:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]) states :

> Returns a new Dataset partitioned by the given partitioning
>   expressions, using spark.sql.shuffle.partitions as number of
>   partitions. The resulting Dataset is hash partitioned.

Maybe your understanding of repartitioning is wrong. When you repartition by a column `c`, then all rows with the same value for `c` are in the same partition, but 1 partition can hold multiple values of `c`

Comment: repartition is api of RDD/spark , not scala , why are you refering scaladoc ? "Dataset partitioned by the given partitioning expressions" from this what should be my partition expression , if I want to partition based on three columns i.e. col("model_id"),col("fiscal_year"),col("fiscal_quarter") ???

Comment: so if I want to achieve rows with the same value for c are in the same partition and no other values are included in that , how can I do it ? i.e. one partition for values of one key.

Comment: @user3252097 you cannot do this with dataframes/datasets, with RDD ist should be possible (using custom partitioner). But do you want to do this, sounds strange to me

Comment: @ Raphael Roth , my objective is to evenly distribute the data , in all partitions . My company has a data since 20 yrs , as it is growing data kept on growing. data has year and quarterly wise stored in tables. If I partitionBy "year", "quarter" , some partitions has few hundred records , for recent yearts it went few miliion records in each quarter , so when I parition as above data is not evenly distributed in all partitions. How can I make data evenly distributed in all parquet files or partitions?
Please suggest me , how and what logic should i follow ?